# What type of variables are needed to pass data between two structs in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, scope, state

I have two pickers on one screen of my app. What I want to achieve is when one selection is made in either picker, the selection updates in both pickers.

So, for example, if I choose  'heat pump' in the user system picker, the current system picker also updates to 'heat pump'. I would like for this situation to work in both directions.

Here is the first picker struct:

```
struct CurrentSystemPicker: View {
// Array of dummy data
let currentSystems: [String] = ["Air Conditioning", "Furnace", "Furance Air Conditioning", "Heat Pump"]
@State var selectedCurrentSystem: String = "Current System"
var body: some View {
    Menu {
            Picker("picker", selection: $selectedCurrentSystem) {
                ForEach(currentSystems, id: \.self) { system in
                    Text(system).tag(system)
                }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))

            }
            .fixedSize()
            .frame(width: ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 275 : 110, height: ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 75 : 50)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 15 : 10)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(
                    cornerRadius: ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 15 : 10)
                .stroke(Color.eSaverGray, lineWidth: 1))
            .overlay(
                Text("\(selectedCurrentSystem)"))
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the second picker struct:

```
struct UserSystemPicker: View {
// Array of dummy data
let userSystems: [String] = ["Air Conditioning", "Furnace", "Furance Air Conditioning", "Heat Pump"]
@State var selectedUserSystem: String = "Future system"
var body: some View {
    Menu {
            Picker("picker", selection: $selectedUserSystem) {
                ForEach(userSystems, id: \.self) { system in
                    Text(system).tag(system)
                }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBackground))

            }
            .fixedSize()
            .frame(width: ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 275 : 110, height: ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 75 : 50)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 15 : 10)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(
                    cornerRadius: ESConstants().IS_IPAD ? 15 : 10)
                .stroke(Color.eSaverGray, lineWidth: 1))
            .overlay(
                Text("\(selectedUserSystem)"))
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these two structs exist in the same main view?
If they exist in the same main view, you can use @Binding inside both structs, with 1 @State variable in the main view for passing data between these two structs. example:

```
struct MainView: View {

@State var getData: String = ""

var body: some View {

 VStack {
  CurrentSystemPicker(bindingData: $getData)
  UserSystemPicker(bindingData: $getData)
 }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get Binding variables to be initialized with a string? For example,
'@Binding var bindingData: String = "some string"'